# How do I get daily Ad stats using the graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

let's say you want the daily Ad performance stats for an account for January. Currently we (inefficiently) achieve this by making 31 calls (one per day of the month of January) like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/act_1376129679271234/stats?access_token=&start_time=1422939600&end_time=1423026000

where start_time and end_time specify a duration of 1 day.

Is there a way where we can achieve this in fewer calls?

Many thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new Ad Report Stats API in which you can specify your time range and `time_increment`which is the number of days of data aggregation (in your case you want to set the `time_increment` to 1).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.2#params

Comment: Many thanks matteo!  I'll report back should I encounter any issues.